# "porn is widespread" or "porn are widespread"

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, countable-nouns, collective-nouns

Which one is grammatically correct?

1. porn is widespread.
2. porn are widespread.

I have found examples of both on the web, does it mean the sentences are correct and both have the same meaning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Porn**, which is short for **pornography**, is a singular noun and, according to the basic rules of standard English grammar, a subject which is singular must agree in form with the verb that goes along with it. Therefore, the form of the verb *to be* that you should be using in this sentence should also be singular:

> Porn is widespread.

**Porn are widespread** is just incorrect. The fact that you found something somewhere on the Internet does not mean that the grammar is going to be top-notch. There are many people of many different backgrounds writing lots of things online and there is no guarantee at all that their English will be prefect. People make mistakes for a million different reasons.